# how do i delete this message in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

i made a clear command for my discord.js bot.
here's the code

```js
if (isValidCommand(message, "clear")) {
  const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
  const amount = args.join(' ');
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("eat poopoo.");
  if (!amount) return message.reply("you haven't given an amount of messages which you want to delete!");
  if (isNaN(amount)) return message.reply("the amount parameter is not a number :|");

  if (amount > 100) return message.reply("you can't delete more than 100 messages :P");
  if (amount < 1) return message.reply("you can't delete less than 1 message dummy");

  message.channel.messages.fetch({
      limit: amount
    }).then(messages => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(messages)
        let s = message.channel.send(`Deleted ${amount} messages`)
```

i want it to delete the message (deleted "amount" messages) after 10 seconds but i don't know how

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout()` if you want to delay something by ten seconds.

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch({
 limit: amount
}).then(messages => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
  message.channel.send(`Deleted ${amount} messages`);
 }, 10000); // 10 seconds in ms
});
```